# Unable to install NVIDIA driver on laptop Lenovo Legion Y530 with a GTX 1060 6GB

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, lenovo

I tried to install NVIDIA driver with software and update application, adding a PPA and install the package nvidia-driver-xxx , using the installer from NVIDIA, but all of these solutions don't work. I tried 390, 435 and 450 versions and I have the same problem.

When I use the software and update application, it give me this error:

[image: Error screenshot]

When I try to use `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx` (I tried with every version the command `ubuntu-drivers devices` gave me,) it says this :

[image: Terminal screenshot]

When I try the nvidia installer (when I run it in console mode), it says:

```
Unable to load the 'nvidia-drm' kernel module
```

I try to install a prior version of the nvidia driver 440 because I used a laptop and since driver 440, my second screen is not detected. I have a Lenovo Legion Y530 with a GTX 1060 6GB using Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows in dual boot.

When i try `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, it gave me the same error as the second screenshot.

Comment: Why would you add a PPA when these drivers are already in Ubuntu repositories?  Also please do not submit pictures of text.  Some people can't read them and most won't.  Please copy/paste any errors here and use formatting tools provided to offset them by formatting as code.

Comment: @singrium It doesn't work, it gave me the same error as in the second screenshot

Comment: @Nmath I use the third method in this [website](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/nvidia#via_un_ppa) (it's a french website and it use this ppa : `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`). Sorry, I'm new in askubuntu

Comment: You didn't need to add a PPA to do this. Nvidia drivers are already in Ubuntu repositories.  PPAs should not be used in place of official repos unless absolutely necessary.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for